# Cannot uninstall angular-cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I've tried several times to uninstall my angular-cli in order to update it but even if I follow the instructions provided on github:

- npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
- npm cache clean
- npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

When I check using the command ng --version I still get the old version :

```
 angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26

 node: 7.7.1
 os: darwin x64
```

How can i fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: Try to reopen console

Comment: I did reopen the console several times...but the issue is still there

Comment: As angular/cli was renamed: `npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli` should do it ... this would all beta versions

Comment: I 've just tried your suggestion. It executes the uninstallation but still when I check with ng -v it shows me the old version...it's really frustrating

Comment: If you're using Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.28 or less, you need to uninstall angular-cli package first.

`npm uninstall -g angular-cli`, 
`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`, 
`npm cache clean`,
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: This is what worked for me on OS X using `nvm` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604991/why-does-angular-cli-version-say-1-after-installing-version-7/53618641

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are facing issue with angular/cli then use the following commands: 
**`npm uninstall -g angular-cli`** to uninstall the angular/cli. 
**`npm cache clean`** to clean your npm cache from app data folder under your username. 
use **`npm cache verify`** to verify your cache whether it is corrupted or not. 
use **`npm cache verify --force`** to clean your entire cache from your system.

Note: 
You can also delete by the following the paths 
`C:\Users\"Your_syste_User_name"\AppData\Roaming\npm` and 
`C:\Users\"Your_syste_User_name"\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` 
Then use the following command to install latest angular/cli version globally in your system. 
**`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`**
To get more information visit [github angular-cli update](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli).

Comment: @WastedFreeTime, after uninstall do npm cache verify --force(this flag is required) then install whatever version you want. This worked for me.

Comment: if following the above answer doesn't work, you may have to redo it and use `--force` flag on `npm cache clean` to make it work.

Comment: I tried all those options, it doesn't work, I have uninstalled Node js, I did delete node folders manually from  C:\User\...\AppData\Roaming\

Answer (score 91):

I have also faced the same issue in recent past for me I have do the following commands one by one in terminal.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
sudo npm cache clean
```

After this run

```
ng -v
```

If still get angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.2x.x then run the following command

```
which ng
```

It will show the ng path. Go to the path and if it is linked with any file remove the same the link and actual ng file. In my case the link is in /usr/bin/ng and actual path of ng file is /lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.

```
sudo rm -rf /lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/ng
```

Next you need to install @angular/cli using

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Close all the terminal and run ng -v and you are on. May be it will help someone. Thanks :)

Comment: Work on Linux...lost 30 minute before finding this solution. THANK YOU!

Comment: `sudo` was not necessary in my case.

Comment: Tried every other way, this was the only one that worked

Comment: Life saver! had an old version of angular on my system and could not figure out how to remove it

Comment: Thanks for all your comments... :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Awesome solution.

Comment: Life saver! stuck and waste too much time but your solution worked for me

Comment: Great answer, the path can be different.  /usr/local/bin/ng  Make sure not to just copy commands from above

Comment: The ONLY working solution on my Linux. "which ng" killed it

Answer (score 35):

[Updating Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli)

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

If you're using Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.28 or less, you need to uninstall angular-cli package first.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Then when it gets done successfully you may try:

ng --version

Answer (score 14):

This sometime happens when you had actually installed @angular/cli using yarn and not npm.

You can verify this by looking in to yarn's global install folder.

You can remove it from yarn using

`yarn global remove @angular/cli`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saved me the crazy search to uninstall the angular cli.

Comment: This deserves some more upvotes :) In my case `yarn global remove` refused to do it; I had to delete it manually. Use `which ng` to find out where it was installed.

Answer (score 9):

You are using the beta version of angular CLI you can do this way.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm uninstall -g angular/cli
```

Then type,

```
npm cache clean
```

Then go to the AppData folder which is hidden in your users and go to roaming folder which is inside AppData then go to npm folder and delete angular files in there and also go to npm-cache folder and delete angular components in there.After that restart your PC and type

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

This worked for me ✌️

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution, first, delete the ng file with

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/ng
```

then install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (you need to restart your terminal to use nvm).

then install and use node 6 via nvm

```
nvm install 6
nvm use 6
```

finally install angular cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

this worked for me, I wanted to update to v1.0 stable from 1.0.28 beta, but couldn't uninstall the beta version (same situation that you desrcibed).
Hope this works

Comment: I've tried everything, nothing seemed to work, then I just executed this `rm $(which ng)` and then `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` and it worked like a charm. So basically I did pretty well without nvm but was forced to remove the ng binary. Bloody hell...

Comment: thanks alot man. I had nvm installed... Didnt know what was wrong

Comment: @Albert : Thanks a lot finally this one works for me

Comment: For me the path to ng is ``/usr/local/bin/ng`` 
Use a `which ng` to locate the path.

Answer (score 6):

The following approach worked for me:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

and

```
npm cache verify
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This doesn't work:

```
npm uninstall -g angular/cli
npm cache clean
```

instead use:

```
npm uninstall -g @ angular/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not get the angular-cli to go away. I FINALLY figured out a way to find it on my windows machine. If you have Cygwin installed or you are running linux or mac you can run `which ng` and it will give you the directory the command is running from. In my case it was running from `/c/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/npm/ng`

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

Step 2:

```
npm cache clean
```

Step 3:

```
npm cache verify
```

Step 4:

```
npm cache verify --force
```

Note:
You can also delete by the following the paths

C:\Users"System_name"\AppData\Roaming\npm and

C:\Users"System_name"\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Then

Step 5:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: why copy pasting answer of somebody else w/o any new input and posting as your own? SO should punish for such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had angular-cli version `1.0.0-beta.28.3`, and the only thing that worked for me was deleting the angular-cli directly from the global node_modules folder:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules
rm -rf angular-cli
```

After that `ng version` output was, as expected:

```
command not found: ng
```

And I could install the latest angular-cli version:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I had an old angular-cli version 6 installed, but it could not be upgraded. I needed to delete it on my Mac OS X using
`rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/angular-cli`
Afterwards, I installed the latest cli as usual and it worked fine
`npm install -g @angular/cli --latest`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use (without @)

```
npm uninstall -g angular/cli
```

because

> If you're using Angular CLI beta.28 or less, you need to uninstall angular-cli package. It should be done due to changing of package's name and scope from angular-cli to @angular/cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

Try to update via these steps found in the npm repo for the [angular cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli).

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

There is also an angular cli [migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc-update). One other option (more involved) is to start a new project and migrate over by copying and pasting certain files. This can be found here in the "moving into the cli" section of the [angular-cli github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-moving-into-the-cli)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the hidden folder ".npm" in your Home directory and delete the old angular-cli folder.

Answer (score 0):

While uninstalling Angular CLI I got the same message (as it had some permission issues):

> Unable to delete .Staging folder

I tried deleting the `.staging` folder manually, but still got the same error. I logged in from my administrator account and tried deleting the staging folder again manually, but to no avail.

I tried this (run as Administrator):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli.
```

Then I tried creating the project from my normal user account and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For those using **Windows**, I had this issue because :

- after running `npm uninstall -g @ angular/cli`, the folder `AppData\Roaming\npm` were still containing a `ng` file
- this file prevented a complete uninstall of the CLI

I tried then to remove the `ng` file manually, but for some reasons it was not possible (I did not have the right), **even as admin**.

The only hack I found was using a 'linux based' command (I used Git bash) as admin and removing this file from command line: 
`cd AppData/Roaming/npm`
`rm ng.cmd`

*For information: this was with the version 6 of the CLI. There is not problem anymore to remove manually this specific file after the update.*