# Can't update angular to version 6

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, angular6

I'm trying to update angular to latest version .

I have updated global @angular/cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then when I try to update local @angular/cli using `ng update @angular/cli` I get this error:

```
Error: Unexpected end of JSON input
Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "apimap",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.11",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "npm": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.53",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

The format is correct.

the project is compiling and working when ng serve.

I'm using v9.9.0 of Node and 6.0.1 of npm.

Heres's tslint.ts file

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "arrow-return-shorthand": true,
    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [
      true,
      "rxjs",
      "rxjs/Rx"
    ],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "order": [
          "static-field",
          "instance-field",
          "static-method",
          "instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-super": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": [
      true,
      "ignore-params"
    ],
    "no-misused-new": true,
    "no-non-null-assertion": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unnecessary-initializer": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      true,
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "typeof-compare": true,
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],
    "directive-selector": [
      true,
      "attribute",
      "app",
      "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
      true,
      "element",
      "app",
      "kebab-case"
    ],
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "invoke-injectable": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Start here: https://update.angular.io/. Follow the steps as laid out after you choose the options that apply to you.

Comment: Followed it but when I make ng update @angular/cli I get the error mentionned

Comment: What about your `angular.json` file?

Comment: angular-cli.json ? Also valid json format

Comment: You mention installing the CLI globally, that is good. Did you install it locally, too? That step is not mentioned in your post.

Comment: Sure I have installed it as it's mentionned in package.json file . after installing locally angular / cli I get this message `updated 2 packages and audited 12544 packages in 24.804s
found 9 vulnerabilities (3 low, 6 moderate)
  run npm audit fix to fix them, or npm audit for details` so I have run npm audit fix to fix them

Comment: I have posted it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just to be sure run the following steps:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Then in your Local project package:

```
rm -rf node_modules dist 
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm i 
ng update @angular/cli 
ng update @angular/core
```

If this doesn't work, I think you should update manually the package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.5",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
```

To remove .angular-cli.json and create angular.json if updated manually

```
  ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

Comment: As last step instead of editing manually run: ng update @angular/cli

Answer (score 2):

Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50965027/1002641

The problem was having ng installed under /usr/local (and a symlink in /usr/local/bin). Removing it, helped me update my @angular/cli version to 6 (from 1.7.1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Removing symlink /usr/local/bin fixed myissue. Thanks a lot.