# Why does Angular CLI version say 1 after installing version 7?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm attempting to update my global version of Angular CLI to the latest version.

Why doesn't `ng v` still show version 1.3.2 after installing?

I'm using `nvm` btw.

---

Before installing...

```
$ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.3.2
node: 10.14.1
os: darwin x64
```

Installing...

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

/Users/U6020643/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin/ng -> /Users/U6020643/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /home/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/home/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile
+ @angular/cli@7.1.1
```

After installing....

```
$ ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.3.2  <-- why isn't this 7.1.1?
node: 10.14.1
os: darwin x64
```

Comment: Since your current installed version is less than 5, see message at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#updating-angular-cli     Also, look at accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version  there in the comments  Mattijs helped me find a solution.  In your case, you can try using npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.1.1

Answer (score 6):

Alright so this is how I appear to have fixed this issue. Again I'm on OS X (Sierra), with Node installed via `nvm`.  Credit to [Cannot uninstall angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070441/cannot-uninstall-angular-cli) for a lead.

---

Locate Angular CLI install

```
which ng
/<home>/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin/ng
```

NVM managed version is linked

```
ls -l /<home>/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin/ng
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  39 Dec  3 20:25 /<home>/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin/ng -> ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```

Remove

```
rm -rf /<home>/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin/ng
rm -rf ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```

Check (wait there's *another* install)

```
which ng
/usr/local/bin/ng
```

Remove this last one

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ng
which ng
<blank>
```

Now reinstall `ng`

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
ng
-bash: ng: command not found
```

Switch node versions using `nvm`

```
nvm use 8 # This just happens to be another version I had installed
```

Switch back the problematic version

```
nvm use 10
Now using node v10.14.1 (npm v6.4.1)
```

Voila

```
ng v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.1.1
Node: 10.14.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.11.1
@angular-devkit/core         7.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.1.1
@schematics/angular          7.1.1
@schematics/update           0.11.1
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6
```

Comment: This perfectly worked for me. My question is, does it behave like this when you have 2 versions of node?

Comment: I believe you should be able to switch your node version using `nvm` and get whatever CLI is installed within that environment.