# Unable to upgrade global angular CLI from 7 to 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I've read several tutorials and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version) on how to upgrade Angular CLI from 7 to 8.  This should be a simple thing to do.  No matter what I do when I run `ng version` I get 7.2.2.

[image]

I've tried running uninstall, install, upgrade, using sudo, specifying `ng update @angular/cli@^8`, `@latest`.  No matter what I get the same result.  I'm not getting any errors either.

I'm using Mac 10.14.6 (Mojave)

How can I run a simple upgrade to angular CLI 8?

Comment: Doesn't `npm install --global @angular/cli` work? It's possible you're inside a directory with its own `package.json` and `ng` runs the local version and you're getting those mixed up.

Comment: That shows that your *global* version is already higher than 7.2.2; it's 7.3.9. No output from the `npm upgrade` command seems suspicious, though. What does `npm list -g --depth 0` show? Are you using the regular registry (`npm config get registry`)?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis - No.  I've already tried this.  Same result.  If you notice in my screenshot I'm not in an app directory.  This is my home directory

Comment: normally the `ng update` take care of everything. could you try to run `ng update @angular/cli`, as specify [here](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0), and check for any error. Maybe paste the output in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: There was a package.json in my home directory for some reason.  I deleted it as it shouldn't exist.  Similar result when running `npm install -g @angular/cli`.  It just changed the `ng v` output to `7.3.9`.  Note, I'm only focused on updating my global angular CLI.  I'm not trying to update a project.

Comment: If you run `npm install -g @angular/cli` it will just **reinstall** the current version. You have to remove it first.

Comment: This question should be closed.  I can no longer reproduce the problem.  The laptop with the issue completely crashed and requires a new hard drive.  Who knows, maybe the hard drive was the problem all along.

Comment: Do you have nvm installed? I could not update from 8 to 10 and after I deactivated nvm it worked.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I ran into same issue on Windows machine and it was happening because of different VS Code instances that I kept open and at the same time I was trying to update the angular-cli from Command Prompt. I closed VS Code instance and then I was able to update angular-cli version.

Answer (score 8):

> I've tried running uninstall, install, upgrade, using sudo, specifying `ng update @angular/cli@^8`, @latest. No matter what I get the same result. I'm not getting any errors either.

That will update the CLI for the `package.json` in the current directory.

You can update the global package like this:

```sh
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: In my specific case this doesn't work.  And I've already tried this.  As I mentioned I tried a ton of things.  I'm still looking into this. Right now it appears I'm unable to uninstall `ng` globally.  See similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070441/cannot-uninstall-angular-cli

Comment: No error.  `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` only outputs `up to date in 0.025s`.  Then I run `ng v` and I still see Angular CLI 7.3.9.

Comment: Find what `.npmrc` files you have on your drive, and check if any are changing where `npm` places the cache.

Comment: My whole laptop crashed while trying to figure this out.  I guess that invalidates my question as I have no way to continue troubleshooting this problem.  Apple is replacing the hard drive under Applecare

Comment: +1 because I appreciate the help you did offer and you deserve credit for helping me figure some things out.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe be caused since the angular versions in global and spec configs are different. you manually update the packages in your package.json and run npm install, or you can use npm outdated