# Angular commands not working after installing angular cli and setting path variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

When I try to create a new project with Angular CLI, with:

> ng n app

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Venkateshwarn 
M\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng:26
                  );
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
     at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
```

How can I upgrade or uninstall Angular CLI?

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070441/cannot-uninstall-angular-cli ?

Answer (score 0):

**To uninstall angular cli you can use this command:**

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
```

you can refer this article to get more knowledge: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli

**To upgrade angular**

Perform a basic update to the current stable release:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

To update from one major version to another:

```
ng update @angular/cli@^<major_version> @angular/core@^<major_version>
```

you can refer this article to get more: https://angular.io/cli/update

Answer (score -1):

It should be solved by reinstalling Nodejs and Angular ClI, first of all uninstall both, and at the end of the reinstallation update Angular CLI.

Comment: Can you write it in english please ?

Comment: No problem :) Remember [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680) ;)