# Angular CLI not getting downgraded

Tags: angular, angular11, angular13

After trying this a couple of times I cannot for the life of me figure out why these commands don't downgrade Angular CLI...

```
ng --version 
//Angular CLI: 13.0.3
//Node: 14.15.4
//Package Manager: npm 6.14.10
//OS: win32 x64
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@11.1.1
ng --version (still getting version 13.0.3. for some reason)
```

Any ideas what could be affecting this?

Answer (score -1):

**You need to use `npm cache verify` instead of `npm cache clean --force`.**

First, ensure the current version of `@angular/cli` is installed in your machine using the `ng --version`.
For removing the current version, you need to run the following command:

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
You may also need to add `sudo` at the beginning of your command if you are facing problems in Linux.

by running `npm cache verify` you can verify the contents of the cache folder, garbage collecting any unneeded data, and verify the integrity of the cache index and all cached data

And then you can install your desired version of `@angular/cli` by running the following command:
`npm install -g @angular/cli@11.1.1`

Comment: I tried with npm cache verify 
Cache verified and compressed:
Content verified: 464 (14864634 bytes)
Index entries: 704
Finished in 1.329s
After that, I installed with command as you said, but got the same result. Installing was successful, but version did not change

Comment: Any luck on installing your desired version after verifying your NPM cache? @StefanSrbljanin

Comment: I was following this article in the end and ended up with the same result:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070441/cannot-uninstall-angular-cli?rq=1

Comment: You may try restarting your computer, reinstalling node.js (and NPM alongside it), and installing them all from scratch.

Comment: Tried restarting the machine, downgrading Node.js to version 12.11.0. Tried doing the whole uninstall/reinstall Angular CLI and I'm getting 'The Angular CLI requires a minimum v12.20' and in package.json I still have @angular/cli version "^13.0.3"

Comment: @StefanSrbljanin, was you able to solve the issue?