# Problems uninstalling Angular Cli

Tags: angular

I want to update my version of Angular but when I try to uninstall it, it throws me the following

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens and it won't let me uninstall?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot uninstall angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070441/cannot-uninstall-angular-cli)

Answer (score 0):

Answer here might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50211580/19263408

- `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` to uninstall the angular/cli.
- `npm cache clean` to clean your npm cache from app data folder under your username.
- use `npm cache verify` to verify your cache whether it is corrupted or not.
- use `npm cache verify --force` to clean your entire cache from your system.