# npm failed to install angular cli, or looks like so

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566257/how-to-uninstall-angular-cli) to unload the old installation with these steps:

```
[sudo] npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
[sudo] npm cache verify
[sudo] npm install -g @angular/cli
```

The last step gave me trouble - the console screen just keep scrolling with this message, till I had to ctrl+C it.

```
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
gyp verb command install [ '8.1.4' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.1.4"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.1.4
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 8.1.4
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.1.4
```

I tried googling it and it seemed to be a npm versioning issue, but with no more useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failing component seems to be the `node-sass` dependency.

This problem could happen due to several issues:

- Does the path `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` exist and is writable? Are you able to install other global NPM packages?
- Historically there were issues installing the CLI on systems with less than 1 GB RAM like in Docker containers and in some CI agents. If this is a VM, try increasing the RAM
- Is your OS supported by node-sass? This is usually never an issue, but just in case. Maybe try installing `node-gyp` package explicitly `npm i -g node-gyp`. Sometimes this helps with packages that need building like node-sass. similarly you might need git if you don't have it

Comment: i used ubuntu 16.04 VM, and memory is sufficient. I did run npm i -g node-gyp explicitly and it went through. Then I tried "npm install -g @angular/cli" again and this time it seemed worked. Thank you!