# Could not find API compiler-cli, function __NGTOOLS_PRIVATE_API_2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to restore an old Angular project.

After an `npm-install` and then `ng-serve` I get the following error

> Could not find API compiler-cli, function __NGTOOLS_PRIVATE_API_2

The error is coming from the @ngtools
package located at  `..node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:8:11)`

my dependencies look as followed

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "angular2-moment": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
    "ng2-toastr": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "moment": "2.15.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.14",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2",
  }
```

If I delete the nodes module folder I can get the Angluar version from `ng -v`

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.14
node: 9.11.1
os: win32 x64
```

What would be the best course of action to get this project working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few steps involved. I started by upgrading the Angular CLI to a slightly more recent version. I guess just trial and error.

1. `npm install angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3`
2. `npm install @angular/core@2.3.1`
3. Fixed an issue with the angular-cli.json outlined [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3566)
4. `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem by running this command:

```
npm i --save-dev @angular/cli @angular-devkit/build-angular @angular/compiler @angular/compiler-cli
```

Basically, it update all involved actors.

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11084)

Answer (score 0):

Running the below command worked for me as well:

```
npm i --save-dev @angular/cli @angular-devkit/build-angular @angular/compiler @angular/compiler-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also coming across this issue. What worked for me in the end was more or less to remove angular cli and re install it with these steps

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

this helped me out
source: [how to uninstall angular cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566257/how-to-uninstall-angular-cli)