# Uninstall Angular and typescript without npm

Tags: angular, uninstallation

I installed nodejs, angular cli and typescript.

I uninstalled nodejs first and nwo I don´t know how to uninstall angular cli and typscript without npm.

Comment: angular-cli is a "node-package", not an 'exe'... you need npm to uninstall it;

Comment: If I uninstalled nodejs this package then uninstalled too, not? sorry for my english, i am spanish.

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer you are looking for in here: [uninstall angular cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566257/how-to-uninstall-angular-cli)

Comment: @41726c as specified, he no longer has npm. So your provided answer woudn't work.

Comment: NodeJS is installed on your OS (MAC, windows)... in case of not installing globally, the "angular-cli" or any other package for that matter may exist in multiple folders where you installed them - you can delete the @angular/cli folders or do it the right way: "install node, go to folder, uninstall packages"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't set up NPM to save your files elswhere, it should be in

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Simply delete the folder to remove the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Check if these folders exist, and remove them if you no longer need them.

If you are using Windows:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

Using mac:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Or nvm on mac:

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/{version}/lib/node_modules/
```