# Errors: Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'

Tags: angular6, angular7

I am getting this error while running my application. Here are the details of my application.

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.3 
Node: 10.15.1 
Angular: 7.2.7 
@angular-devkit/architect -0.13.3 
@angular-devkit/build-angular- 0.800.1 
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer - 0.800.1 
@angular-devkit/build-webpack - 0.800.1 
@angular-devkit/core -7.3.3 
@angular-devkit/schematics -7.3.3 
@angular/cli -7.3.3 
@ngtools/webpack -8.0.1 
@schematics/angular -7.3.3 
@schematics/update 0.13.3 
rxjs 6.3.3 
typescript 3.2.4 
webpack 4.30.0
```

I have already tried cache clean.

Comment: Here is the detail of my application.
Angular CLI: 7.3.3    Node: 10.15.1   Angular: 7.2.7
@angular-devkit/architect -0.13.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular- 0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer -  0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack  -   0.800.1
@angular-devkit/core  -7.3.3
@angular-devkit/schematics -7.3.3
@angular/cli -7.3.3
@ngtools/webpack -8.0.1
@schematics/angular -7.3.3
@schematics/update                0.13.3
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.30.0

Comment: This issue is generally because of incompatible packages. Have you recently updated package.json?

Comment: No i haven't update package.json file.

Comment: Finally i found the solution.
1)Firstly eliminate all changes in package.json file by giving simple command git checkout package.json.
2)Then after make change in package.json in @angular-devkit/build-angular- ~0.800.1(Add tail instead of cap)   
3)Then run command rm -rf node_modules/
4)Then clean catch by giving command npm clean cache -f
5)And at last run command npm install.
This works for me.

Comment: Above, `npm clean cache -f` is wrong, should be `npm cache clean --force` .

Comment: What I found is that I had set nvm to use the wrong version of node, needed to set that properly using `nvm use 12.14.01` (in my case)

Answer (score 193):

In your package.json change the devkit builder.

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.1",
```

to

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.0",
```

it works for me.

Comment: Made it to `@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.4"` and it worked.

Comment: Perfect. Worked with "0.13.4", and running npm build afterwards

Comment: Landed here because I got a notification about a security vulnerability detected in js-yaml < 3.13.1. After updating that I got this error message. Anyways, `"^0.10.0"` fixed it.

Comment: the 0.13.4 worked for me, however make sure you remove the node_modules folder first, delete the package-lock.json and then run npm install.  seems to fix everything.

Comment: This solution works but it's wrong, you should instead upgrade the angular and angular cli version. Check @ovangle answer below

Comment: Perfect. Worked with "0.13.4", and running npm build afterwards

Comment: Please refer to @abasar answer. It should resolve the issue.

Comment: This answer is outdated, refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043569/6122411

Comment: Even though the comments above are stating this solution is outdated, it worked perfectly for me in June 2020. How you found this out is beyond me, but take my upvote!

Comment: This answer was upvoted and does not clearly give a reason or source to support the response aside from "it works for me."

Comment: @angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.4" and running npm install, worked for me

Answer (score 121):

Following worked for me

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.0
```

Comment: Although this answer is direct, it as well lacks resource or reference. Blindly directly people to install a particular package version may disrupt their entire project. Please be clear and provide some reference.

Comment: npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.4 worked

Answer (score 86):

Everyone here is focusing on downgrading @angular-devkit/build-angular to @angular 7.x versions for compatibility, but what they *should* be doing is to upgrade `@angular/cli` to angular 8 versions.

The problem is that the system cli is still stuck at an old version and isn't automatically updated by `ng update` (because it is outside the angular controlled project), so it is being left at an incompatible version when trying to access the angular libraries.

Downgrading `@angular-devkit/build-angular` just causes more incompatibilities.

```
npm i --global @angular/cli@latest
```

will fix the problem *without* breaking things elsewhere.

Comment: This should be the answer. This error occurred to me because I pulled from a branch that has been updated to Angular 8 but my computer's angular is still Angular 7.

Comment: this issue can occur when you do `npm audit fix` on projects that are still on `angular@7` so sometimes downgrading `@angular-devkit/build-angular` is the correct answer

Comment: running `npm audit fix` sometimes introduces braking changes. we should instead run `npm audit` to understand the findings and upgrade the package 1 by 1 using something like `npm i --save-dev <package@version>`

Comment: Upgrading `angular-cli` is WORSE than downgrading devkit packages. The correct versions to downgrade/upgrade should depends on your current CLI version. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043569/6122411

Comment: @zhuhang That is just patently false. You can expect upgrading the global CLI to be backwards compatible with the last few versions, you cannot necessarily expect it to be forwards compatible.

Comment: @ovangle I did not mention forward compatible. I am saying people should not blindly upgrade or downgrade, especially the `angular-cli` version. One should identify their current CLI version and use the devkit that matches that CLI. If you want to upgrade devkit packages, then upgrading CLI altogether is correct.

Comment: @ovangle besides, in most cases, the devkit got updated accidentally, so the author sees the error. Author should downgrade the devkit, instead of upgrading CLI.
However, if author indeed needs the latest devkit, then the author definitely SHOULD upgrade his CLI to a matching version.

Comment: Perfect answer. Upgrade instead of a downgrade.

Comment: I also had to resolve the CHOWN issue for EACCESS errors.  The hints on this involved setting the ownership for ~/.npm, and I had to, also, set for ~/.npm-global

Answer (score 82):

Everyone is focusing on downgrading `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version to X, or upgrading `@angular/cli` version to Y or latest.

However, Please do not **blindly** suggest an `X or Y or latest` as answers. *(Though usually, downgrading devkit should be better because upgrading CLI is a breaking change)*

The correct version to choose, always depends on your Angular (angular-cli) version.

```
Angular CLI v8.3.19 -> 0.803.19
Angular CLI v8.3.17 -> 0.803.17
Angular CLI v7.3.8 -> 0.13.8
Angular CLI v6-lts -> 0.8.9
```

For other specific versions, visit: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tags. Find your CLI version, and in some tags, they do mention the corresponding versions for `@angular-devkit/**` packages.

**Note: If you want to upgrade your CLI version, you should first consider upgrading to latest of your major version, do not simply jump to the next major version.**

Comment: Not sure why this answer was down-voted; it is good advice.
In fact, it solved my problem (as I had upgraded my `devkit/build-angular` package to `0.803.x` but left my Angular CLI at `7.3.x`.  Since I didn't intend to upgrade my Angular CLI, I went back to using ver `0.13.x` of devkit

Comment: @GreggL In fact, my answer is better than the one with most upvotes. Other answers simply suggests to upgrade/downgrade BLINDLY. As my answer suggests, the correct CLI/ devkit version correlates, but no one gives a F, because that's how the dev community is.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, tx ! But do you have any idea for cli 7.0.6? [It doesn't written there](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v7.0.6)

Comment: To add to this great answer :

In my own project, I include `@angular/cli` in the dev dependencies and I make sure it matches the `@angular-devkit/build-angular`. That way I can maintain multiple projects with multiple CLI version.

If you do `ng s` it will use your computer CLI, if you do `npm start` (which is a script in `package.json` to do `ng serve` it will actually use the local CLI it launch this app with the right CLI.

Hope this helps

Comment: Updated for Angular 9, as of today (source [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular?activeTab=versions)): 0.901.1 -> latest, 0.1000.0-next.0 -> next, 0.8.9 -> v6-lts, 0.803.26 -> v8-lts, 0.13.10 -> v7-lts

Answer (score 31):

Your @angular-devkit is incompatible with @angular/cli version, so just install older one like this for example:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.8 @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr@0.13.8
```

Comment: Wanted to post the same one. Seen `0.12.4` floating around, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @M.Doe The correct version depends on your 1angular-cli` version. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043569/6122411

Answer (score 27):

Same issue after trying to upgrade to Ng8 which failed due to dependency issues.

> `npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular`

then I used,

> `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.12.4`

fixed it...

Comment: sometimes this solution is not feasible because it's version might not someone's requirement. Delete package lock json
`npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular
`

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, but I solved it thanks to the comment of Ekta Gandhi:

> Finally i found the solution.
>
> 1) Firstly eliminate all changes in package.json file by giving simple command git checkout package.json.
>
> 2) Then after make change in package.json in @angular-devkit/build-angular- ~0.800.1(Add tail instead of cap)
>
> 3) Then run command rm -rf node_modules/
>
> 4) Then clean catch by giving command npm clean cache -f
>
> 5) And at last run command npm install. This works for me.

.... Along with the modification proposed by Dimuthu

> Made it to @angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.4" and it worked.

Comment: It should be noted that version "0.13.4" of @angular-devkit/build-angular has an issue when using lazy loaded components.  To avoid that issue users need to update their @angular-devkit/build-angular package...   So sort of a trade off here...

Answer (score 9):

This happened to me when I installed Angular 8, there are some incompatibilities I couldn't solve. I had to downgrade because I went down the rabbit hole juggling around with every version until I found one that worked.

First, TypeScript was outdated, the default installation added a reference to TypeScript 3.1.6 and it requires 3.4 or greater.

`npm install typescript@">=3.4 <3.5"`

Second, using the devkit 0.800.1 or 0.800.1 always ended up in incompatibilities. I tried many combinations but I am not sure it's fully compatible yet, specially because I am using one bootstrap a bit older and I cannot upgrade yet.

Finally I tried to downgrade (go to package.json and find the devDependencies) until one of them worked.

`@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.4"`

I am sure your problem is dependencies versions but I cannot tell you which one. Give it a try downgrading.

Comment: Whilst it works, I would suggest `@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.8"`as it seems to be the latest version that works

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems by bootstrap version or dependencies don't let me go higher than 0.13.4 but it would work for many people

Comment: With 0.13.8 (essentially anything lower than 0.800.*) I get: `An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser
See "/tmp/ng-5iKcHN/angular-errors.log" for further details.`
With latest version I get error from title.
What to do now?

Answer (score 7):

I was also coming across this issue and for me when doing more updates more issues occurred.

What worked for me in the end was more or less to remove angular cli and re install it with these steps:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

this helped me out
source: [how to uninstall angular/cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566257/how-to-uninstall-angular-cli)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue and struggled hours to solve it, I have tried all of the above options but nothing solved my problem. This issue occurs due to version mismatch of angular/cli and angular-devkit, so I did the following :

1. Manually changed version of files:

   @angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",

   `@angular/cli": "~7.0.3",`        //This is for Angular7, for Angular8 : 0.803.23
2. Deleted package-lock.json
3. Executed : npm install

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

On my side it was package

> @angular-devkit/build-angular

and

> @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr

was not the same version, Updating `build-ng-packagr` to same version as `build-angular` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your moving to angular 8 or 9 this will do the trick

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply audit your code and then

```
#sudo su 
rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules
sudo npm i --save
```

Answer (score 0):

What actually worked for me was to update the application and its dependencies with:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

[Angular documentation](https://angular.io/cli/update)

Answer (score -1):

You have incompatibly dependencies  i solved this problem by change the package.json form another project angular and then after change to this packag.json, you change only the dependencies versions you have.

after the change write:

-npm link

-npm serve -o

then it's work :)

```
   {
   "name": "angular-jwt-auth",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
   },
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
   "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.1",
   "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
   "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
   "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
   "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
   "@angular/material": "^7.3.1",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
   "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
   "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.0",
   "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
   "angular-6-datatable": "^0.8.0",
   "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
   "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
   "core-js": "^2.5.4",
   "jquery": "^3.4.1",
   "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
   "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
    },
   "devDependencies": {
   "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
   "@angular/cli": "~7.1.0",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
   "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
   "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.53",
   "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
   "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
   "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
   "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
   "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
   "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
   "karma": "~3.1.1",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
   "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
   "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
   "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
   "protractor": "~5.4.0",
   "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
   "tslint": "~5.11.0",
   "typescript": "~3.1.6"
   }
```

Comment: I have tried it and it give me same error errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(es5BrowserSupport).

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, this is how i have solved it.
The problem mostly is that your Angular version is not supporting your Node.js version for the build.
So the best solution is to upgrade your Node.js to the most current stable one.

For a clean upgrade of Node.js, i advise using n. if you are using Mac.

```
npm install -g n
npm cache clean -f
sudo n stable
npm update -g
```

and now check that you are updated:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

For more details, check this link: [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/04/29/how-to-upgrade-nodejs-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Would be happy to know why i got this downvote.
This is a clean answer, without trying to have some "workarounds"

Comment: because its not related to node version, it should be angular-cli version.

Comment: I just had this issue, i don't think it's the angular-cli version, it IS related to the angular-cli but it affected by the node version.

Answer (score -1):

**NONE of the above-given answers works for me.**

My original goal was to fix the sometimes **CONSTANT COMPILING** of my project with VSCode.

I tried many, many ways, but **NOTHING** was working -- the project just **WON'T COMPILIE!**

Finally I found out what the problem here is:

**I cloned the project from my company's repository, and all the code from there HAS TO go exactly with the versions of dependencies when the existing part of the project was coded.**

In the end, I deleted the previously cloned project **AGAIN (quite a few times)**, and cloned **AGAIN (also a few times)**, and **DID NOTHING BUT RAN "npm install", and everything started to work**.

**The lesson I learned here is that:**

Sometimes you'll make the situation worse when you try to fix some problems (the one I had was the **CONSTANT COMPILING** of my project).

But it doesn't mean we cannot try to fix the problems. We can. But when everything becomes a mess, we'd better go with the original code.

Fortunately the **CONSTANT COMPILING** of my project happens only once a while, not all the time. It's not fixed, but I have to bear with it, otherwise my project won't even compile.

Answer (score -2):

it's work reinstall @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.4

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.4 --save-dev
```