# Ionic problem: [ng]Schema validation failed with the following errors:[ng]Data path".builders['app-shell']"should have required property 'class'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

affter I update the ionic4 to ionic5 and try to run the ionic app the server is broken and show me this Error :

> [ng] Schema validation failed with the following errors: [ng] Data
>   path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
>
> [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

---

I am try to change the @angular-devkit/build-angular node package as I have managed to resolve this issue by rolling back my back down from ^0.800.0 to ^0.12.4. 
by this way: npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.12.4
by this way :

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.0"

"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.0"
```

it solve the problem but give me this error :

> [ng] Schema validation failed with the following errors: [ng]   Data
>   path "" should NOT have additional properties(es5BrowserSupport).
>
> [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

and still not work

---

this is the package json:

```
`{
  "name": "ionicchattingapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.12.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "\u0016git remote add origin https://github.com/Omar-Sh1/nodeChatApp.git\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[A\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b[C\u001b\u001b[B"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "chatting"
  ],
  "license": "ISC"
}
`
```

and this is the Angular json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "defaultProject": "app",
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": false,
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-build": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-serve": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-serve",
          "options": {
            "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build:production",
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You would likely have to supply more code to make sense of this.

Comment: @JGFMK I am Edit The Question I hope be more Clear

Comment: I updated package.json from 
       "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.1"
to
       "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4" ran "npm install" and it fixed it for me.

Comment: @tkerwood finally it's work thanks

Answer (score 106, accepted):

From the above comment session @tkerwood provide solution for this.

Updated **package.json** from `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.1"` to `"~0.13.9"`

run `npm install`

Comment: Can someone explain me why there is a version 800? I can't imagine any reason to skip 68 versions

Comment: I had to move to version "~0.13.9" for this to work https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular/v/0.13.9

I went for the highest version number not in the range of 800

Comment: @PieterDeBie They jumped more than 68 versions, they went from 13 to 800 :P
The reason is that people in the Angular ecosystem like to share same version numbers. Version 0.800 is for Angular 8 and version 0.900 for Angular 9. Version 0.13 was for Angular 7. Hence if you are you using Angular 8+ You should not use this solution, look at other responses and use the version of the devkit that matches your version of CLI

Comment: @LeroyMeijer Version "~0.13.9" is the latest for Angular 7

Answer (score 19):

Everyone is focusing on downgrading `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version to X, or upgrading `@angular/cli` version to Y or latest.

However, please do not **blindly** try switching `X or Y or latest`. *(Though usually, downgrading devkit should be better because upgrading CLI is a breaking change)*

The correct version to choose always depends on your Angular (angular-cli) version. I've listed a few versions here.

```
Angular CLI v8.3.19 -> 0.803.19
Angular CLI v8.3.17 -> 0.803.17
Angular CLI v7.3.8 -> 0.13.8
Angular CLI v6-lts -> 0.8.9
```

For other specific versions, visit: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tags. It might take some digging but once you locate your CLI version, in some tags they do mention the corresponding versions for `@angular-devkit/**` packages.

**Note: If you want to upgrade your CLI version, you should first consider upgrading to latest of your major version, do not simply jump to the next major version. *Answer used from [zhuhang.jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393158/errors-data-path-buildersapp-shell-should-have-required-property-class/59043569#59043569)**

Comment: This is, IMHO, a much better answer than the one that has a large vote share.    However, the tags website is not very clear to me, oh well!!!

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day (more strictly speaking: two days) haha.

Answer (score 3):

Angular Cli 8 support Node Js 10.9+. I have Node.js 8, after update to 10.16 works fine.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me as well,

1. npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
2. npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.12.4