# Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'

Tags: angular

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.

Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
    at MergeMapSubscriber._registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validatorResult [as project] (D:\repo\beauty-velvettes-web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:210:42)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (D:\repo\beauty-velvettes-web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:65:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (D:\repo\beauty-velvettes-web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:55:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\repo\beauty-velvettes-web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (D:\repo\beauty-velvettes-web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:84:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (D:\repo\beauty-velvettes-web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:25:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\repo\beauty-velvettes-web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (D:\repo\beauty-velvettes-web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:52:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\repo\beauty-velvettes-web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (D:\repo\beauty-velvettes-web\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:77:26)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic problem: \[ng\]Schema validation failed with the following errors:\[ng\]Data path".builders\['app-shell'\]"should have required property 'class'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506473/ionic-problem-ngschema-validation-failed-with-the-following-errorsngdata-p)

Answer (score 195):

Try to update the `package.json` file so that `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.1"` reads `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4"`

Then run `npm install` in the command line.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56537342

Answer (score 61):

This worked for me.

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular

npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.0
```

Comment: Worked for me, I was having 
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 10.7.0
Angular: 8.2.14
Thanks

Comment: Make sure you add the --save-dev to put this in the devDependencies since this isn't needed at runtime

Answer (score 26):

Most of the answers are correct in stating that this occurs either because of a mismatch between:

- Nodejs version and Angular version

OR

- `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version and angular version

Also, this issue is most likely to occur if you either:

1. upgraded/downgraded Nodejs version (which is no longer compatible with the angular version)
2. Upgraded Angular version
3. Run `npm audit fix`

For 1, check the Nodejs version support needed here: https://angular.io/guide/setup-local and check the installed version. If you are using the latest version of angular, you should be able to make it work with the latest version of Nodejs.

For 2, did you follow instructions here: https://update.angular.io/ ? If yes, and still have issues, look for any issues already created or create an issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

For 3, `npm audit fix` updates the `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version to a higher version because `@angular-devkit/build-angular` does not follow proper versioning (major releases still update only the minor version). Check the link below to check the compatible version for your Angular version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular?activeTab=versions Use the correct version and the issue will be fixed.

P.S: This is a good read about angular versioning: https://angular.io/guide/releases

Comment: `npm audit fix` wrecked it for me too. This seems like a bug with the command. It shouldn't break my app, it's called "audit fix" not "audit break"

Answer (score 18):

Try to update `@angular/core` using `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

Answer (score 12):

Angular Cli 8 support Node Js 10.9+. After update Node.js to 10.16 works fine.

Comment: Yes, that happened to me because I used NVM to switch to version 8, and I forgot to switch back to version 10, and I was surprisingly getting this error!

Answer (score 12):

Just found this answer from another link,

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.0
```

Answer (score 8):

Update @angular-devkit/build-angular to "^0.13.9" . Then run `npm install`
and after that, run `npm serve`.

Specs:

Angular: 7.2.15
Angular CLI: 7.3.9 
Node: 11.2.0 
OS: darwin x64

Comment: Did you mean `ng serve`?

Comment: Not exactly, @melikesahin, 'ng serve' could work on a different way on old angular versions. 'npm install' and 'npm serve' have worked well on Angular: 7.2.15 and Node11 in order to getting rid of the errors above mentioned. If you are considering to give 'ng serve' a try, please share the outcome. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Below worked for me.

```
> 1. npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular 

> 2. npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.0
```

if we use

**AVOID**:    npm audit fix -f

it may create problem, so dont use it.

Comment: This works for me and you are right, npm audit fix is the root cause.

Comment: Yes, This worked for me as well, Even I had used "npm audit fix" command

Answer (score 3):

What i did was to uninstall and install the "^0.13.0".
I confirm/ support this last  answer. It worked for me as well.
I had uninstall version "^0.800.0" and installed the "^0.13.0".
rebuild your project it will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when upgraded angular from 6 to 8.

Simple update angular cli to latest version & node version to 10+.

1) Visit [this link](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) to get the latest node version. Angular 8 requires 10+.
2) Execute **npm i  @angular/cli@latest** to update cli.

This is what I have currently

[image]

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). That terminal output could be copy-pasted into a code block and use less bandwidth and be easier for screen readers to read and people to copy-paste.

Answer (score 3):

This is worked for me

1. npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
2. npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.0

Answer (score 2):

I have to say, if you don't want to change anything in `package.json` file, try to update your Node.js version to latest. (currently 12.13.1 LTS)

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue when installing Bootstrap.

The following commands are what worked for me:

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular

npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick for you:

1. Update your angular cli by running the command `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`
2. Run or build your project by running the commands `ng s` or `ng build` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

1. Opened package.json
2. Changed "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.0" to "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.0" or changed Changing from
   "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.802.1"     to
   "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9"
3. Run npm install
4. Run ng serve

The original version can be diferent, but is necessary change it at 0.10.0 or 0.13.9 version that fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

1. open cmd from current project
2. npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
3. npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

In package.json

Changed "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.0" -->
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.0"
Then:

```
 npm install
 ng serve
```

Specs:

Angular CLI: 6.1.5
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.9