# Schema validation failed with the following errors @angular-devkit

Tags: angular

While start NgServe I getting the below error. 
I have cleared the cache multiple times and also updated the NPM.
while installing NPM i have not got any issues. 
Using Angular NGServe Command I'm unable to proceed further. 
Kindly help in proceeding further and let me know in case of any further details required.

```
ng serve
Your global Angular CLI version (7.3.9) is greater than your local
version (7.1.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
    at MergeMapSubscriber._registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validatorResult [as project] 
    (C:\workspace\web\space\POC\app-ui\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:215:42)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\workspace\web\space\POC\app-ui\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\workspace\web\space\POC\app-ui\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\workspace\web\space\POC\app-ui\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\workspace\web\space\POC\app-ui\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\workspace\web\space\POC\app-ui\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\workspace\web\space\POC\app-ui\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (C:\workspace\web\space\POC\app-ui\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\workspace\web\space\POC\app-ui\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\workspace\web\space\POC\app-ui\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic problem: \[ng\]Schema validation failed with the following errors:\[ng\]Data path".builders\['app-shell'\]"should have required property 'class'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506473/ionic-problem-ngschema-validation-failed-with-the-following-errorsngdata-p)

Comment: Problem already solved her https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542518/schema-validation-failed-with-the-following-errors-data-path-buildersapp-sh

Answer (score 1):

ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
try this