# npm run start gives error Schema validation failed with the errors: Data path "" should have required property 'browserTarget'

Tags: angular, single-spa-angular

I cloned a git repo (Angular ver 11, Single SPA) to my local machine.
The whole team needs to maintain the same version as in the package.json.

1. First I executed the command `npm install`
2. Then I gave  `npm run start`

I am getting the below issue

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:   Data path ""
> should have required property 'browserTarget'.

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "integration",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "npm run build:single-spa:integration",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "build:single-spa:integration": "ng build integration --prod --deploy-url http://localhost:4220/",
    "serve:single-spa:integration": "ng s --project integration --disable-host-check --port 4220 --live-reload false"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "6.0.0",
    "guid-typescript": "1.0.9",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "primeicons": "4.1.0",
    "primeng": "11.3.0",
    "rxjs": "6.6.0",
    "single-spa": "5.3.4",
    "single-spa-angular": "4.9.2",
    "tslib": "2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "11.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

**Update **

Below is the angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "integration": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "integration",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/integration",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.single-spa.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "extra-webpack.config.js",
              "libraryName": "integration",
              "libraryTarget": "umd"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1000mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "1000mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "none"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "outputHashing": "none"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "integration:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "integration:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "integration:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          },
          "e2e": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
            "options": {
              "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
              "devServerTarget": "integration:serve"
            },
            "configurations": {
              "production": {
                "devServerTarget": "integration:serve:production"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "integration"
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

**Edit - Additional Info**

`npm run build`  and `ng test` works fine with the same setup.

Comment: Why do you want to use single-spa.?

Comment: Could you please share the `angular.json` code as well?

Comment: @MikeOne That's our requirement to create an Angular App with Single SPA.
All 10 teams should follow the same version

Comment: @MilanTenk I have updated with the angular.json.

Comment: Please note my update comment ==> npm run build and ng test works fine with the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61080357/10832261
Since you cannot change versions in package.json, maybe node version could solve your issue: "check the Nodejs version support needed here: https://angular.io/guide/setup-local and check the installed version. If you are using the latest version of angular, you should be able to make it work with the latest version of Nodejs."

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  We are expected to use Angular 11. Am very new to Angular. If I change node version will it not impact the versions mentioned in the package.json? If so can you please help me do that? I couldn't understand from the link you've shared.

Comment: Which node version do you use? You can find this out by typing "node -v". You need 10.13.x/12.11.x or later minor. To manage node versions I'd recommend using nvm (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: Node version in my system is v14.16.0
Should I be changing the version? If so please guide me.

Comment: As I stated, it should be 10.13.x/12.11.x or later minor, so you probably need to downgrade. For this, try "nvm use <required version>".