# `ionic serve` is only deploying locally - not in DevApp

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, ionic-devapp

I have an Ionic4 app that I'm trying to run on my iPad's DevApp with `ionic serve`. However, it only seems to be serving locally...

```
ionic serve
> ng run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ng...

[INFO] Development server running!

       Local: http://localhost:8100

       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

[INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:8100!

[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
[ng] 
[ng] Date: 2019-06-27T22:09:04.521Z
[ng] Hash: e5b1e27f4608e1891cc1
[ng] Time: 25929ms
[ng] chunk {_pages-private-new-order-order-confirmation-order-confirmation-module} _pages-private-new-order-order-confirmation-order-confirmation-module.js, _pages-private-new-order-order-confirmation-order-confirmation-module.js.map (_pages-private-new-order-order-confirmation-order-confirmation-module) 13.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {common} common.js, common.js.map (common) 6.24 kB  
 ... and 164 additional chunks
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

I tried using `ionic serve --address ...` with my IP address, but I get this error...

```
Provided host could NOT be bound. Please provide a different host address or hostname
```

I also tried `ionic serve --devapp`, but then I get this error...

```
Data path ".builders['cordova-build']" should have required property 'class'.
```

**I'm new to Ionic, so I could be missing something basic. Any ideas?**

Comment: try ionic serve --address 0.0.0.0

Comment: That added `External: http://192.168.170.234:8100` but still no sign of `devapp`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have [upgraded your Ionic CLI from 4 to 5 but not the other related packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506473/ionic-problem-ngschema-validation-failed-with-the-following-errorsngdata-p).

Try:

- Open **package.json**
- Update the line from `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "(version number here)"` to `"^0.800.6"`
- run `npm install`

Note: The linked post says update to `"^0.12.4"` but it seems like they have misunderstood the version numbers as this is a significantly older release. I would try updating to the latest version first.

Comment: When I change it to "^0.800.6", I get this error after running `ionic serve` - `Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.`

Comment: have you tried starting a new project with `ionic start` and the testing if that works. This will rule out if its a system issue or if its something to do with that specific app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> ionic cordova run ios -l --devapp

Ref https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-run

Ionic CLI was updated to v5.2.1 recently, it has changed a few things.