# Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'. Error:

Tags: angular, package.json

I run

```
npm audit
```

and this command gives me 9 vulnerabilities (5 low, 2 moderate, 2 high) and it asked me to run:

```
npm audit fix
```

after that when I run `npm audit` I have not any problem, but when I tried to lunch my applictation:

```
ng serve
```

I had the flowing error:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
at MergeMapSubscriber.project (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/AngularTests  estSilaboSecurity/silabo/silose_frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace /workspace.js:215:42)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/AngularTests /testSilaboSecurity/silabo/silose_frontend/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:69:27)
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/AngularTests/testSilaboSecurity/silabo/silose_frontend/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:59:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/AngularTests/testSilaboSecurity/silabo/silose_frontend/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/AngularTests/testSilaboSecurity/silabo/silose_frontend/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:92:26)
at InnerSubscriber._next (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/AngularTests/testSilaboSecurity/silabo/silose_frontend/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/AngularTests/testSilaboSecurity/silabo/silose_frontend/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
at MapSubscriber._next (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/AngularTests/testSilaboSecurity/silabo/silose_frontend/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:55:26)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/AngularTests  /testSilaboSecurity/silabo/silose_frontend/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/localdata/hasanh/Documents/websites/AngularTests   /testSilaboSecurity/silabo/silose_frontend/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:86:26)
```

I tried many responses: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506473/ionic-problem-ngschema-validation-failed-with-the-following-errorsngdata-p/56537342#56537342) but I still have the error, here is my package.json file:

```
{
 "name": "mat-silabo",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "scripts": {
 "ng": "ng",
 "start": "ng serve",
 "build": "ng build",
 "test": "ng test",
 "lint": "ng lint",
 "e2e": "ng e2e"
 },
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.7",
"@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/cdk": "~7.3.6",
"@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
"@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.6",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "~7.1.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.9",
"@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^5.0.9",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "^7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "~3.1.6"
 }
}
```

Thanks for your Help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errors: Data path ".builders\['app-shell'\]" should have required property 'class'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393158/errors-data-path-buildersapp-shell-should-have-required-property-class)

Comment: Hi, I found this link before and I tried all solutions, but every time the vulnerabilities (2 low, 3 moderate, 3 high) come-back and when I rune
`npm audit fix`  they are fixed and angular-devkit/build-angular is set to "^0.901.7"