# Ionic Create a PWA: Schema validation failed in CLI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, command-line-interface

I want to create a simple PWA app with the IONIC Framework

I tried several tutorials all over the internet, but I could not get them to work. Still new to Ionic.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xm_EZAGGGdU

https://github.com/designcourse/ionic-4-crash-course-project-restrr

After npm install and ionic build when I want to view the page (ionic serve) it fails in the cli.

Solutions mentioned in this thread: [Errors: Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393158/errors-data-path-buildersapp-shell-should-have-required-property-class)

Did not work for me.

> [ng] Schema validation failed with the following errors: [ng]   Data
>   path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
>
> [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Updated package.json from "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.xxxx"
  to "^0.12.4"
- delete folder node_modules
- Run npm install

See if that works.