# Build falling using docker

Tags: django, angular, docker, docker-compose

I am setting up a repository that uses docker name evalai . I have previously also used it. But from 2 to 3 days it's not working it is giving me these two errors.

:-TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
:-Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.

I have tried changing angular version also and used docker-compose up and docker-compose up --build also but it is not starting front end.

```
Starting evalai-ngx_db_1  ... done
Starting evalai-ngx_sqs_1 ... done
Starting ngx_django       ... done
Starting evalai_ngx          ... done
Starting evalai-ngx_worker_1 ... done
Attaching to evalai-ngx_db_1, evalai-ngx_sqs_1, ngx_django, evalai_ngx, 
evalai-ngx_worker_1
db_1         | 2019-12-30 11:03:04.871 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 
address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1         | 2019-12-30 11:03:04.871 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 
address "::", port 5432
db_1         | 2019-12-30 11:03:04.878 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix 
socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1         | 2019-12-30 11:03:04.925 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was
shut down at 2019-12-30 10:58:31 UTC
db_1         | 2019-12-30 11:03:04.936 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is 
ready to accept connections
db_1         | 2019-12-30 11:03:05.949 UTC [29] LOG:  incomplete startup 
packet
sqs_1        | 11:03:05.691 [main] INFO  org.elasticmq.server.Main$ - 
Starting ElasticMQ server (0.8.5) ...
sqs_1        | 11:03:07.495 [main] INFO  
o.e.rest.sqs.TheSQSRestServerBuilder - Started SQS rest server, bind 
address 0.0.0.0:9324, visible server address http://localhost:9324
ngx_django   | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
ngx_django   | wait-for-it.sh: db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
sqs_1        | [INFO] [12/30/2019 11:03:08.855] [elasticmq- 
akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://elasticmq/user/IO-HTTP/listener- 
0] Bound to /0.0.0.0:9324
sqs_1        | 11:03:08.869 [main] INFO  org.elasticmq.server.Main$ - === ElasticMQ server (0.8.5) started in 3820 ms ===
evalai_ngx   | Schema validation failed with the following errors:
evalai_ngx   |   Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
evalai_ngx   | Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
evalai_ngx   |   Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
evalai_ngx   |     at MergeMapSubscriber.project (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:215:42)
evalai_ngx   |     at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:69:27)
evalai_ngx   |     at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:59:18)
evalai_ngx   |     at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
evalai_ngx   |     at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:92:26)
evalai_ngx   |     at InnerSubscriber._next (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
evalai_ngx   |     at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
evalai_ngx   |     at MapSubscriber._next (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:55:26)
evalai_ngx   |     at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
evalai_ngx   |     at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:86:26)
evalai_ngx   |     at InnerSubscriber._next (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
evalai_ngx   |     at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
evalai_ngx   |     at /code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:17:28
evalai_ngx   |     at Object.subscribeToResult (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
evalai_ngx   |     at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:65:54)
evalai_ngx   |     at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:55:14)
evalai_ngx exited with code 1
worker_1     | [2019-12-30 11:03:14] INFO Using /tmp/tmpn99wkr8y as temp directory to store data
worker_1     | Traceback (most recent call last):
worker_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
worker_1     |     "__main__", mod_spec)
worker_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
worker_1     |     exec(code, run_globals)
worker_1     |   File "/code/scripts/workers/submission_worker.py", line 770, in <module>
worker_1     |     main()
worker_1     |   File "/code/scripts/workers/submission_worker.py", line 699, in main
worker_1     |     if eval(LIMIT_CONCURRENT_SUBMISSION_PROCESSING):
worker_1     | TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
evalai-ngx_worker_1 exited with code 1
ngx_django   | Operations to perform:
ngx_django   |   Apply all migrations: account, accounts, admin, auth, authtoken, challenges, contenttypes, django_ses, hosts, jobs, participants, rest_framework_expiring_authtoken, sessions, silk, sites, web
ngx_django   | Running migrations:
ngx_django   |   No migrations to apply.
ngx_django   | Starting the database seeder. Hang on...
ngx_django   | Are you sure you want to wipe the existing development database and reseed it? (Y/N)
ngx_django   | Exception while running run() in 'scripts.seed'
ngx_django   | Performing system checks...
ngx_django   | 
ngx_django   | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
ngx_django   | December 30, 2019 - 11:03:32
ngx_django   | Django version 1.11.23, using settings 'settings.dev'
ngx_django   | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
ngx_django   | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Here is the docker_compose.yml file

```
    version: "3"
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:10.4
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  sqs:
    image: pakohan/elasticmq
    hostname: sqs
    ports:
      - 9324:9324

  django:
    container_name: ngx_django
    hostname: django
    env_file:
      - docker/dev/docker.env
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/dev/django/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
      - "sqs"

  worker:
    env_file:
      - docker/dev/docker.env
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/dev/worker/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - "django"

  angularjs:
    container_name: evalai_ngx
    hostname: angularjs
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/dev/angularjs/Dockerfile
    environment:
      ANGULAR_ENV: development
    ports:
      - "8888:4200"
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - "django"
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    - /code/node_modules
```

Here is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "evalai",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "doc:build": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json",
    "doc:serve": "compodoc -s",
    "doc:buildandserve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json;mkdir -p documentation/src/assets;cp -R src/assets/images documentation/src/assets/;compodoc -s",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.12",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^3.0.0-rc.2-1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.8",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-textarea-autosize": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-twitter-timeline": "^0.1.5",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.15.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.15",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.2.0"
  }
}
```

My OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
   Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838

and for more file you can look into this repo :- https://github.com/Cloud-CV/EvalAI-ngx

Comment: How would somebody reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Suryansh.p can u show us your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml? Or any additional scripts u are running?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393158/errors-data-path-buildersapp-shell-should-have-required-property-class

Comment: i have attached docker file and also i have tried changing angular version but no luck