# PWA not working on build version, only on prod build version on localhost

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular9

So I'm working on this [school project](https://favoritereads.be/books) and I'm trying to implement PWA. However, it doesn't seem to work like it should.

I added PWA to the project and it seems to work fine when I execute the `ng build --prod` command and then run a http-server by using the `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 .\dist\Bookstore\` command. However, in order for this to work I had to modify my `main.ts` file like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393158/errors-data-path-buildersapp-shell-should-have-required-property-class).

I'm guessing the problem has to do with how it's build and that's why it's not working on [my school project live build](https://favoritereads.be/books)? Or could it have to do with the fact that my website does not enforce HTTPS and HTTP links don't redirect to HTTP, because if I'm not mistaken a PWA requires HTTPS or production version in order to function? EDIT: HTTPS works now.

```
//Main.ts file

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import 'hammerjs';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('ngsw-worker.js');
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Builder version: `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.6"`

```
//manifest.webmanifest

{
  "name": "Bookstore",
  "short_name": "Bookstore",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "./",
  "icons": [...] //Shortened for obvious reasons
}
```

Comment: Yes HTTPS is a requirement for is to be a valid working PWA

Comment: Also, run the lighthouse tool to discover hints to fix any other issues you may have. Looks like you may need to adjust your start_url

Comment: @Mathias Thanks for you answer! I tooled around a bit with the lighthouse tool and changed my `scope` and `start_url` to various things, but I can't seem to find what would make it work. Do you have any idea? I added the manifest.json file up here.

Comment: Is your PWA @ /books ? Have you tried putting that in the start_url? or are you doing some sort redirect to that?

Comment: In angular routing the path `''` redirects to `'books'` and I did try putting that there, but I'm not aware how much of an importance `.` and `/` are in the start_url, because I'm not 100% sure on what variants I've tried.