# Can't build angular project - Getting Error - Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

When trying to build angular project, i'm getting to following error:

Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
at MergeMapSubscriber._registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validatorResult [as project] (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:215:42)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
at MapSubscriber._next (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)
at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
at C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:17:28
at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:65:54)
at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\Projects_GIT\Topocad_2020\StoreWeb\topostore.desktop\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:55:14)

The package.json file:

```
The package.json file:

{
  "name": "topocad-mng-app",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve topoStore --port 4202",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev": "ng build topoStore --base-href /TopoStoreApp/ --output-path=DEV/TopoStoreApp",
    "dmz": "ng build topoStore --base-href /TopoStoreApp/ --output-path=DMZ/TopoStoreApp --configuration dmz",
    "stage": "ng build topoStore --base-href / --output-path=STAGE/TopoStoreApp --configuration stage",
    "prod": "ng build topoStore --base-href / --output-path=PROD/TopoStoreApp --configuration production",
    "start-dev-lior": "ng serve topoStore --configuration=devLior"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.10",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.3.1",
    "@types/json-schema": "^6.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.5",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "primeng": "^7.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^10.1.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tsickle": ">=0.34.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.2.4"
  }
}
```

[cli version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Ytb.png)
it's stopped working after installing node new version.

I have tried to reinstall angular cli and Node.js.
Tried the suggestions from this question [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393158/errors-data-path-buildersapp-shell-should-have-required-property-class)
but all avail.
Other project works well.

any other suggestions?

Thanks, Asaf Levy

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3) you have a table with the compatibility of Angular CLI, Angular, Node.js, typeScript and Rxjs

It's looks like you're using angular version not compatible with your rxjs version.

Change the package.json and use `npm install`

Comment: Thanks, But it didn't help.