# I cant remove my global angular-cli version(1.0.0-beta.28.3) whatsoever on my windows machine

Tags: angular

I cant remove my ***angular-cli version(1.0.0-beta.28.3)*** whatsoever. Tried these in vain:

```
npm uninstall angular-cli -g

npm cache clean --force

npm cache verify
```

Finally tried uninstalling nodejs too but even that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
it'll may works,
[same qus link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566257/how-to-uninstall-upgrade-angular-cli).

Comment: `npm install -g @angular/cli ` First fire this command it updates your angular cli and then Fire `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` this command

Comment: don't uninstall your nodejs its just an environment to support your angular cli