# Trying to install Angular CLI v.10.2.3, but it always installs me v.17?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've been trying to install the 10.2.3 version of Angular CLI on my project with `npm install -g @angular/cli@10.2.3`, but when I run `ng version` it shows me that the Angular CLI v.17 is installed instead.

Is this normal?

Comment: If you are running this command in an Angular 17 workspace, this would be expected behavior.

Comment: v10.2.3 is nearly three years old. Why not use any more current version?

Answer (score 1):

You already have `angular cli V17` installed globally.

You have to uninstall that first. Follow the instructions in [uninstalling angular cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566257/how-to-uninstall-upgrade-angular-cli)

Then run

`npm install -g @angular/cli@10.2.3`

edit:

if You need to install a different version of angular on a specific project you need to install it on that project only. you can do so by running the install command above without the `-g` param

Comment: doesn't work sadly, it still shows me v.17 installed

Comment: if you are in an already made angular project folder run this instead : npm install @angular/cli@10.2.3 . installing it this way will only install angular 10 on the current project folder.

Comment: this works, thanks. SInce I'm here, it still gives me the same error when I try to build :"This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^17.0.0,
but Angular version 10.2.3 was found instead."

Only things at v.17 are build-angular and core. How do I downgrade them?

Comment: Why are you trying to build an Angular 17 application with Angular CLI version 10? This makes no sense at all.

Comment: unfortunately you can not downgrade an angular project. but you can create a new angular10 project template using the angular/cli 10 that you just installed. 
I also edited my answer to answer your initial question.

Answer (score -2):

No, it's not normal. It looks like the older version didn't override the newer version that was already installed on your system.
First, uninstall the currently installed Angular CLI globally using-

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

then install -`npm install -g @angular/cli@10.2.3`
now check the version `ng version`

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights. If this is the case here, please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: That's not a duplicated comment, I am trying to explain that try uninstalling using that cmd instead of opening the link that was pasted on the previous comments and reinstall as the older version might not be overridden. Please read the reply fully before commenting on someone's comment.

Comment: Uninstalling the CLI package and installing it again in a specifc version is exactly what the other answer recommends. Please add some explanation **to your answer** that provides more insights